# Change Active Class

Tags: vba, class, element, explorer

I'm having a problem with changing tab within Internet Explorer. I've added an image link below:

DOM Explorer (Elements):
[image: DOM Explorer (Elements)]

I'm trying to select the one with the ID of `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel5_tab` but I'm unable to make it process. I was wondering what the VBA would be to make it do this?

This is what I currently have:

```
element = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel5_tab")
element.Click

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
```

I'm sorry I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to assign an object to a variable, you need to use the `Set` keyword in front of that variable.

So, try using

```
Set element = IE.Document.getElementById( _
    "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel5_tab")
element.Click
```

However, if you are only going to use that element once in your entire project, sometimes it makes sense not to even use a variable at all:

```
IE.Document.getElementById( _
    "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel5_tab").Click
```

Comment: Thank you, the variable had previously been set on another element and has been working fine without it.
I'll try it tomorrow, thank you.